How to calculate the gradient of a radial function
Let $\Omega = B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^N$. I have to determinate for which $\alpha > 0$ such that
$$
u(x) = ||x||^{-\alpha} \quad \text{for} \quad x \neq 0
$$
is in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. I found a book in which they show that it is for $\alpha \in (0, \frac{N-p}{p})$, but they use that
$$
\nabla u(x) = \frac{\alpha}{||x||^{\alpha + 1}},
$$
calculating the derivative as usual, but this is a radial function and its the weak derivative, not the usual one. Can someone tell me why the derivative is that way?
I have done the exercise assuming this but I want to understand why the derivative is that way. Thanks in advance!

What you wrote is not $\nabla u$ but $|\nabla u|$. In fact $\nabla u = \frac{\alpha}{|x|^{\alpha + 2}} x$. When $\alpha < N-1$ you have that $\nabla u\in L^1(\Omega)$ and the fact that the distributional derivative is the same as the strong derivative is just integration by parts.

I´m trying to integrate by parts using a function $\varphi$ in $D(\Omega)$ but I don't know hot to "integrate" u.

In the classical sense, we have in $ {\Omega} \setminus  \left\{0\right\}$
\begin{equation}{\partial }_{{x}_{i}} u = -\frac{{\alpha} {x}_{i}}{{\left\|x\right\|}^{{\alpha}+2}}\end{equation}
Let us suppose that $0  \leqslant  {\alpha}  <  N - 1$, which implies
that $ u \in  {L}^{1} \left({\Omega}\right)$ and
$ {\partial }_{{x}_{i}} u \in  {L}^{1} \left({\Omega}\right)$.
If $ {\varphi} \in  \mathcal{D} \left({\Omega}\right)$, we have the
derivative in the sense of the distributions
\begin{equation}\left\langle {\partial }_{{x}_{i}} u , {\varphi}\right\rangle  =-\left\langle u , {\partial }_{{x}_{i}} {\varphi}\right\rangle  =-\int_{{\Omega}}^{}\frac{1}{{\left\|x\right\|}^{{\alpha}}} {\partial }_{{x}_{i}} {\varphi} \left(x\right) d x\end{equation}
We use Fubini's theorem to integrate this with respect to $ {x}_{i}$ first and integrate this by parts with respect to $ {x}_{i}$. It gives
\begin{equation}\left\langle {\partial }_{{x}_{i}} u , {\varphi}\right\rangle  = \int_{{\Omega}}^{}-\frac{{\alpha} {x}_{i}}{{\left\|x\right\|}^{{\alpha}+2}} {\varphi} \left(x\right) d x\end{equation}
As $  \frac{{\alpha} {x}_{i}}{{\left\|x\right\|}^{{\alpha}+2}} \in  {L}^{1} \left({\Omega}\right)$, this is equal to
\begin{equation}\left\langle -\frac{{\alpha} {x}_{i}}{{\left\|x\right\|}^{{\alpha}+2}} , {\varphi}\right\rangle \end{equation}
This proves that the derivative in the sense of the
distributions is equal to the usual strong derivative
in this case.
